# Interpretation of cross correlation

Tags: cross-correlation

I need some help on the interpretation of crosscorrelation between x=credit and y=GDP, please. Here I have the results of the cc.test function in r. What I know so far, is that if the value of crosscorrelation lags is higher than the present value, it can be an indicator that X can lead Y, and if the values of the lead are higher, X can have a lag relationship with Y. So, in this case, what will be the interpretation? Because on both sides they are significant. Thank you.

[image: Cross correlation X= credit, Y=GDP]

Comment: Are those years or months?

Comment: They are quarters